# Login screen: Save username and password

Tags: android

After deciding to get some exposure to android app, i started playing with it but being new to java and new environment is a good learning curve. However after many hours I was able to get the basic android app going. Now I have another dilemma. I dont have a login screen. I can connect to database just fine but I want users to enter their login one time when they start the app. I have these questions

1. Any good tutorials that I can find where there is a login screen that I can add on top of the work I already got done and once they login, they get directed to those files
2. How do I set the menus. Like if the users setup the login one time and later on they want to change it and use another login, how would I go about setting those?

Any links to good tutorials about this will be very appreciated

Comment: here is the code to get u started.. has everything welcome screen & login ..stores data in sharedpref http://androidsamples.blogspot.in/2009/06/how-to-use-http-connection-saxparser.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they are logged into the app and wan to logout and in with another user name, I would recommend creating a menu option to Sign Out which would take them back to the login screen. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html

For the login screen itself, you could use a `LinearLayout` or `RelativeLayout`. It's really up to you, though.
http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/index.html

As far as links to tutorials, the two above would likely help, but they don't necessarily cover exactly what you're wanting. Google can always be a good friend, though.